# How too make regular toast and or colored toast 

Tags: android, android-layout, option-type, android-toast

I'm wanting make regular toast and a colored toast if possible and wondering of I have too use min engine?

I haven't tried much?

Comment: Their is also one called min_engine can you add color when creating one of those?

Comment: May [this library](https://github.com/usman18/TastyToasty) help you.

Comment: I just insta 

Answer (score 0):

Toast message custom deprecated you can use Snackbar so you can create color and background and so more

Comment: How do I make a snackbar?

Comment: Yes Please check link for snackbar with custom view

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-a-snackbar-in-android/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/custom-snackbars-in-android/

Comment: It said too add code too activity_Main but I don't see it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's about about toast you can try fancytoast
visit this link

https://github.com/Shashank02051997/FancyToast-Android

I have personally tried it one of my projects and it works wonder there are six types only but its great and east to use

It's implementations is

```
FancyToast.makeText(yourContext, "I'm a Toast", duration, type, boolean value).show();
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about?

Comment: And I'm confused about the build.gradle?

Comment: @RileyPQ1462 you want to show colored Toast Message or Regular Toast Message in your android App right?

Comment: Yeah but I'm confused on what you're talking about?

Comment: So it's very simple add this dependency in your gradle file under dependencies section
`implementation 'io.github.shashank02051997:FancyToast:2.0.2'`
and then where you want to apply the toast message rather then using the default Toast use the above line in the answer it work's the same way as our normal toast message

Comment: Where is the build.gradle file or location? Or do I half make one?

Comment: On the left side can you see Gradle scripts with elephant icon?
inside that you can see build.gradle(module ) open that file and add the dependencies
then you can use the above line in you project for Toast

Comment: Wait what were is it like on desktop laptop I'm confused on what's happening?

Comment: You are using android studio? open you project in android studio and on the left you can see the gradle files

Comment: Oh you're using android studio?

Comment: You can use visual studio as well but whichever is it it doesn't affect the files arrangements... you should be able to see it

Comment: Okay I will try